Chaos Theory: how to go from time series to phase space?
I've been reading "Chaos: Making a New Science" by James Gleick, and I came across the following visualization which relates time series data to phase space. However, I can't quite make sense of it.
Images of making portraits in phase space (from Chaos: Making a New Science by James Gleick:

Is there a transformation going on to go from the time series to the phase space? If so, is the transformation invertible?

I don't know this book and what the author explained. From the nomenclature it is pretty clear that a time series is the function $t\mapsto x(t)$ while a curve in phase space is the image of the trajectory $t\mapsto (x(t),\dot x(t)),.$ This curve can be parametrized differently than with $t$ and still look the same. In that sense the transformation is strictly speaking not invertible.

Skimming now through a bit: for an author of a book of that sort (popular science by journalist background) he does a pretty good job at explaining to his typical readers what a phase space is on p. 136. Case closed.

You have x = f(t), i.e. just one-dimensional space only. Thus you need to kind of cheat and create another dimension, which can be done by calculating a derivative. Now you have two dimensions and can draw x = f(t) against its derivative (velocity) - and you get a phase portrait.
You can also explore the system using a return map:
x = f(t)
y = f(t+Δt)
which shows the relationship between the value of the function at one time and its value at a later time, allowing to identify patterns and structures.

At each point on the line in the phase space you have a position $x$ and a velocity $v$ (in physics the phase space is the position-momentum space, or any two canonically conjugate variables). An initial velocity and position are all you need to integrate Newton's equations and find the trajectory $x(t)$ at all times (provided that Newton's equation is such that there is a solution and it's unique).
Conversely, if you are provided with the trajectory $x(t)$, you just have to derive it in time and find $v(t)$: now you have the curve in the phase space.
This shows how to uniquely go from one to the other: the transformation is invertible because Newton's equations (i.e., the equations of motion of the dynamical system under study) are second-order in time. See also this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4178199/532409
